# HTML editor changes code

Tags: html, ads, adsense

I am using a Website builder to build my site, but they have blocks you can add in to allow custom html.

But everytime I try to paste the adsense code, it changes it slightly.

This is what I paste

```
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- News Bottom -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXX"></ins> <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script>
```

And this is what it changes it to

```
<script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
 News Bottom 
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXX"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

The only differences are the first two lines. The first one adds ="" right after the async, and on the 2nd line it just ignores the fact that it is supposed to be a comment. I figured for the comment I can just delete it, as it shouldn't affect the ad.

But how does that first change affect the ad? Can this be why my advertisement's status is still new, or did I just not wait long enough?

Comment: Yes, deleting the comment should be perfectly safe. Did you try pasting `async="1"`? Most scripts would treat that identically.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Tried what? Paul Cantrell's comment (which should be an answer instead) covers the bases. I'd leave the async attribute as-is since it should be interpreted the same way anyway.

Comment: Yes, I tried Paul Cantrell's comment. I just don't see why the advertisement chooses not to show up.

Comment: Is this a new website? This could very well be because Google isn't yet posting real ads on your site, and only using the initial blank ad that precedes approval.

Comment: Well it is a new site, but I know that after you are already approved, they don't need to approve each new site, which is the case for me. But maybe it has something to do with the fact that it is a new ad unit?